# Change filename on file upload in .net (asp)

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to change file name on upload ?

I have such code :

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Upload" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

public class Upload : IHttpHandler {
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
       HttpPostedFile oFile = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];
     string newFileName1 = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@context.Request["orderID"]);
     string newFileName2 = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@context.Request["productCombinationString"]);
     string newName;
       if(newFileName2 != "" && newFileName2 != null && newFileName2 != "<!--@Ecom:productCombinationString-->") {
           newName = newFileName1 + newFileName2 + oFile.ContentType;
       } else {
           newName = newFileName1 + oFile.ContentType; 
       }

     string sDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@context.Request["folder"]);
     oFile.SaveAs(sDirectory + "/" + oFile.FileName);
     if (!Directory.Exists(sDirectory)) Directory.CreateDirectory(sDirectory);
     context.Response.Write("1");
   }
   public bool IsReusable {
      get { return false; }
   }
}
```

And if i change oFile.Filename to newName it does not work ... what is the problem ? :)
Thank you

Comment: 'it does not work' = ?  What does/doesn't it do, what error/exceptions do you get?

Comment: it works with oFile.SaveAs(sDirectory + "/" + "test"); but does not work with oFile.SaveAs(sDirectory + "/" + newName ); so whats wrong with string variable ? Sorry i am new to .net :) so dont really know how to catch exceptions..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your Custom File Name along with Directory to `SaveAs` Method

```
oFile.SaveAs(sDirectory + "/" + "abc");
```

Comment: how i said : if i change oFile.SaveAs(sDirectory + "/" + oFile.FileName); to oFile.SaveAs(sDirectory + "/" + newName); It does not work ...

Comment: actually this works ... so whats wrong with the string variable ? because  oFile.SaveAs(sDirectory + "/" + newName); dows not work

Comment: It should work the string variable as well. Debug and check the value of that File and Directory variables.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 // Get the extension of the uploaded file.
 string fileName = Server.HtmlEncode(FileUpload1.FileName);
   string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);
 string newName;
       if(newFileName2 != "" && newFileName2 != null && newFileName2 != "<!--@Ecom:productCombinationString-->") {
           newName = newFileName1 + newFileName2 + extension ;
       } else {
           newName = newFileName1 + extension ; 
       }

    oFile.SaveAs(sDirectory + "/" + newName );
```

Comment: does not work, only way it work when i change newName to some string for ex. oFile.SaveAs(sDirectory + "/" + "test"); this works , so whats wrong with string variable ?

Comment: can you check what do you get in "newName" ? oFile.ContentType will not give you extension of the file. you have to generate proper filename with extension (i.e.   .xls,.pdf,.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example i used when saving an image look at the save as section

```
////saving file in the physical folder;

FileUpload FileUpload1 = file_Image;

string virtualFolder = "~/Resourceimages/";

string physicalFolder = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(virtualFolder);

string PhotoName = ((string)Session["UserName"] + (string)Session["UserSurname"]);

FileUpload1.SaveAs(physicalFolder + PhotoName + FileUpload1.FileName);

string location = virtualFolder + PhotoName + FileUpload1.FileName;

webservice.UpdateResourceImage((int)Session["UserID"], location);

lbl_Result.Text = "Your file " + FileUpload1.FileName + " has been uploaded.";

Image1.Visible = true;
Image1.ImageUrl = location;
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this code but I do want to point out two things of from the original code:

The first is this order of operations:

```
 oFile.SaveAs(sDirectory + "/" + oFile.FileName);
 if (!Directory.Exists(sDirectory)) Directory.CreateDirectory(sDirectory);
```

I believe it should be this instead.  In the above sequence, there is a potential edge case of saving into a non-existing folder.  This ensures that the folder is created:

```
 if (!Directory.Exists(sDirectory))
 {
      Directory.CreateDirectory(sDirectory);
 }
 oFile.SaveAs(sDirectory + "/" + oFile.FileName);
```

The other thing is that you might be running into issues with `/` as the path separator. I think it should be much safer to do something like:

```
 var saveLocation = Path.Combine(sDirectory, oFile.FileName);
 oFile.SaveAs(saveLocation);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
string uploadFolder = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "UploadFile\\";
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(uploadFolder + "Test"+ extension);
            Label1.Text = "File uploaded successfully as: " + "Test"+ extension;
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "First select a file.";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private string UpdateFilename(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            filename = Server.HtmlEncode(FUJD.FileName);
            string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename);
            filename = filename.Replace(extension, "");
            return filename + '-' + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + extension;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```